# Playstore publish apk split by ABIs

Tags: android, apk, publish, abi

I recently came accross a problem, that I hope you could resolve.

I created an Android app, and split its APK by ABIs (explained [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits)). So after compiling, I find myself with 4 APKs (x86, arm, armv7 and mips).

Everything looked good, so I tried publishing. I assigned different version code to each APK and published them one by one.

Unfortunately, Google Playstore tells me that no devices are compatible for each APK (and therefore there are no device compatible with my app at all). If I remove the split and get a universal APK however, more than 7K devices are compatible.

I really need to publish this app for each ABI, so what am I doing wrong ?